# Multiple-Language Support website in asp.net with C#, Records are coming form SQL Server

Tags: asp.net

Thanks in advance, i know this is very repeated and very much asked question but i did not get any proper solutions i refer lots of sites for this.

problem: i am developing, and ordering site and that is needed to multiple language support like English, Spanish, French, Arabic and almost 10 languages are there. how can i manage all the things from css to images, record fetching from database lots of things are there in my mind to set things.

i can use one solution i can create field for each language in table like for Description i need to keep filed for English, Spanish like this....

What is the best way to use dynamic language translation without any third party tool used.

Please tell me solution.

if you not getting my question please ask me.

i need desperate help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can base your work on localisation and globalisation

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms247246%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

In order to begin you can test theses functionalities

```
Generating Default Resource File :
```

In Visual Studio designer, click the designer surface or a control.

Select Tools --> Generate Local Resource

An XML - based local resource file for the Web page in the App_LocalResources folder with Text and ToolTip 
values for all existing controls on the page, as well as the page title will be generated.

```
Generating Resource Files for Other Cultures:
```

In Solution Explorer

Right click the 'Default.aspx.resx' file and click the Copy

Right click the App_LocalResources folder and click the Paste

Right click the 'Copy of Default.aspx.resx' and click the Rename

Type the new name for the resource file that includes the new language and culture code before the extension.

Comment: what about my Content do i need to save all content with each field with each language ?

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as database thing is concerned, the solution is you will have a `Languages` table and your every user will have a language in database against its record or user can select language from dropdown on the page. All the entity tables like i say, `UserStatus`, `UserTypes` etc will have a relevant lang table like: `UserStatus_Lang`, which will hold the language specific texts, like:

```
UserStatus Table
UserStatusId
1

UserStatus_Lang
UserStatusId_FK    LangId_FK    Text
1                  1            Online
1                  2            ******
```

While saving you will save Id of entity table but while displaying you will show text from `_Lang` table.

Than for controls like labels etc on page, you will create a table `Pages`, which will hold page names of your pages, than another table `PageControls` to hold controls that exist on your page and than another table `PageControlsText` which will hold language specific texts against the page controls. In Page_Init event you will fetch pagecontrols and their texts (according to selected language) from database and set text of pagecontrols by searching them on the page.

I hope you have got some idea about this implementation. 
==============================MODIFICATION===================================

PAGE TABLE

```
PAGEID     PAGENAME   [OTHER COLUMNS]
```

PAGE CONTROLS TABLE

```
PAGECONTROLID      PAGEID_FK    PAGECONTROLNAME    [OTHER COLUMNS]
```

PAGE CONTROLS TEXT TABLE

```
PAGECONTROLID_FK     LANGID_FK     PAGECONTROLTEXT
```

As far as your description thing is concerned you will have to do it like in 2 tables
TABLE1

```
ID          ITEM_NAME
```

than another table TABLE1_LANG

```
ID_FK       LANGID_FK        DESCRIPTION
```

By using this approach you will not need to modify your structure, when new language is introduced in the system.

Comment: do you want me to save control name in database ? and what about content let me give you example i am adding one table like
_______________________
ID ITEM_NAME DESCRIPTION
_______________________

Do i need to save all language Description with particular field like DESC_ENG DESC_ARABIC etc ... ?

Comment: I have added a section MODIFICATION in my answer, kindly check it for your answers, yes you will have to save control names in database.

Comment: I am going offline, so won't be able to reply for some time, leave me any queries that you have and will respond when I get online.

Comment: i am working on this, will let you know as things goes on way, sorry for late reply